# How to interpolate a HSV color?

Tags: c, windows, progress-bar

I am creating an application in win32 api, which will use a progress bar. This progress bar, should change its color. From red (left end) to green(right), and in the middle some yellow.

I searched a little, and found out, that I should use HSV to achieve this. I just don't know how? I found in [this](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/t_convert.html) link, two functions, to convert the color, from RGB to HSV and back.

But what should I do if the color has been converted to HSV?

Comment: You vary the H value from 0 (red) to 120 (green). For more information look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

Comment: How? Just by incrementing it? Or is there some logic which should be applied?

Comment: `for (hue = 0; hue <= 120; hue++)` sort of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like `RGB` coordinates, `HSV` coordinates define a point in a three dimensional space.

You may find a *trajectory* form one point (x0, one color) to the second (x1) with a formula like:

```
x = x0 + alpha * (x1-x0)
```

with alpha varying form 0.0 to 1.0

You can do this for all three components simultaneaously.

With a *trajectory* from green to red in HSV space you will mainly modify the H (Hue) value. If you want to see some yellow in the middle of your path (and not violett) you need to define a second or even third color and walk

```
green -> yellow -> red
```

---

**Edit: Example**

```
int hue0 = 0; // red
int hue2 = 120; // green

// find 100 colors between red and green
for(double alpha = 0; alpha <= 1.0; alpha += 0.01)
{
     hueX = hue0 + alpha * (hue1 - hue0);
     // same for value, saturation:
     // valX = val0 + alpha * (val1 - val0)
     // ...
     // plot this color
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe show me a simple example? I can't find one, and I really don't understand it. Once I've seen it, it will be easier to understand.

Comment: ok, but how do i use that in a win32 api? nothing happened. the color didn't changed. and what is alpha in my case? and what is is hue1? you declared hue0 and hue2. and how do i define a second or a tird color. sorry, i really don't understand. I didn't think, that a simple progressbar is that complicated. :(

Comment: Well, your request "smoothly change from one color to another" **is** complicated, given that _color_ is a 3d space and human perception is complicated. All your other questions should becoime separate SO questions.